# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I was trying to run  following Query on my sql server :

```
CREATE TABLE `e_store`.`products`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
    `brand_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `category_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `attributes` JSON NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`) ,
    INDEX `CATEGORY_ID`(`category_id` ASC) ,
    INDEX `BRAND_ID`(`brand_id` ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT `brand_id` FOREIGN KEY(`brand_id`) REFERENCES `e_store`.`brands`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
    CONSTRAINT `category_id` FOREIGN KEY(`category_id`) REFERENCES `e_store`.`categories`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I have already brands and categories tables on my e_store database.

But I got the following Error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`) ,
    INDEX `CATEGORY_ID`('category_id' ' at line 6
```

Comment: which version of db you are using .. ?

Comment: I'm  using XAMPP, 10.1.19-MariaDB

Comment: SELECT VERSION;

Comment: you use MariaDB than why you tag "mysql"?

Comment: @denny MariaDB is still close enough dialectically. This is a rare divergence

Comment: On which Mysql version you are running the query?

Comment: But... the "client" version is irrelevant.

Comment: XAMPP by default came with 10.1.19-MariaDB ...

Answer (score 19):

For those who are facing this issue similar to me:

MariaDB does not natively implement the JSON data type but it uses it as an alias for `LONGTEXT` for compatibility reasons. According to the documentation (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/):

> JSON is an alias for `LONGTEXT` introduced for compatibility reasons with MySQL's `JSON` data type. MariaDB implements this as a `LONGTEXT` rather, as the JSON data type contradicts the SQL standard, and MariaDB's benchmarks indicate that performance is at least equivalent.
>
> In order to ensure that a a valid json document is inserted, the JSON_VALID function can be used as a CHECK constraint.

So if you are having issues with the `JSON` data type in MariaDB, simply just change to `LONGTEXT`. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting error for JSON datatype.

For Mysql 5.7 you can get help from below link.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

You can check vesrion using below query.

```
select version() as 'mysql version'
```

Comment: @scaisEdge the [JSON *table* type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-json-table-type/) in MariaDB 10.0.16 is completely unrelated to JSON columns.

Answer (score 3):

"`JSON`" is parsed in the server.  `JSON` is one of the points of divergence.

MySQL 5.7 introduced the `JSON` datatype, which matches your syntax.

MariaDB 10.0.16 introduced a `ENGINE=CONNECT table_type=JSON` which does not match your attempted syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You have given single quotes in your index definitions instead of backticks

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `e_store`.`products`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
    `brand_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `category_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `attributes` JSON NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`) ,
    INDEX `CATEGORY_ID`(`category_id` ASC) ,  -- Changed single quotes to backticks
    INDEX `BRAND_ID`(`brand_id` ASC) ,   -- Changed single quotes to backticks
    CONSTRAINT `brand_id` FOREIGN KEY(`brand_id`) REFERENCES `e_store`.`brands`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
    CONSTRAINT `category_id` FOREIGN KEY(`category_id`) REFERENCES `e_store`.`categories`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: that's not the solution I guess, because I have already checked with that ..nothing came out. ..means same error i'm getting