# mariaDB JSON support in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, mariadb, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to create a json database in XAMP, while using the phpmyAdmin it showed me that I'm using mariaDB but in my `xamp-control panel v3.2.2` it shows running `mySQL on port 3306`. I'm using Laravel 5.4 framework to create the database, following is my migration which I'm trying to execute:

```
Schema::connection('newPortal')->create('pages', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique()->index();
    $table->json('styles')->nullable();
    $table->json('content')->nullable();
    $table->json('scripts')->nullable();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now while executing this I'm getting following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json null, `content` json null, `scripts` json null, `deleted_at` timestamp null' at line 1 (SQL: create table `pages` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `title` varchar(191) not null, `slug` varchar(191) not null, `styles` json null, `content` json null, `scripts` json null, `deleted_at` timestamp null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

Even if I keep not null it throws the same error. I want to have json formatted data, I checked the supported version and as per the documentation json format support started from the version `MariaDB 10.0.16.` and I'm using `10.1.21-MariaDB`

Help me out in this.

Comment: Have you tried running that query in a database GUI or REPL and then commenting each part of the query out line by line? It may shed some light on what the exact problem is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185598/1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds)

Answer (score 9):

Since `MariaDB` version 10.2.7; the`JSON` data-type is an alias for `LONGTEXT`.

If you are having issues with the `JSON` data-type in MariaDB, simply just change it to `LONGTEXT`. ;-)

Or add MariaDB JSON to Laravel with [this package](https://github.com/ybr-nx/laravel-mariadb)

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.7 and i'm not able(ot i don't know how) to configure mariadb driver to be used for db connection. 

I'm getting:
Database [mariadb] not configured.

Does anyone know how can i set up it?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the 1064 complained about the datatype "json".  Such is not (yet) implemented in MariaDB.

You can get close with [*Dynamic Columns*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/dynamic-columns/#dynamic-columns-functions), which at least has a way of fetching them into JSON syntax.

Another thing (probably what you are referring to) is [`CONNECT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-json-table-type/) being able to have a JSON *table type*.  (Not *column* type.)

MySQL 5.7 has a datatype called `JSON`, plus a bunch of functions to manipulate such.

Comment: As @ybr-nx points out, MariaDB 10.2.7 (July 12, 2017) added "JSON" as a datatype alias to facilitate replication from MySQL to MariaDB.

Comment: How can I know what error number 1064 means? Can you show me where you looked up?

Comment: @Tony - 1064 means "syntax error".  It is a common problem.  The "near..." part almost always says exactly where the problem is -- either the first token in the message or the last toke just before it.  In this example, it was pointing right at "json".  A quick check of the syntax for the version showed that "json" was not known.  (But later versions implemented such.)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a simple workaround (not recommended for production) -

As per mariadb version 10.1.32 and lower it seems like mariadb does not support json data type I am still unsure if it is available in version 10.2.7+.

but here's a simple workaround to get through this.

change json data type into text and then run your migration again.

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27993070/41234555-19c5d1d8-6dbf-11e8-9a4b-0644b03aecfc.png)

source-
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13622

Answer (score 1):

Add MariaDB JSON support to Laravel by running this command using composer:

```
composer require ybr-nx/laravel-mariadb
```

If you are using **Larvel 5.3 and 5.4** do these two items:

- Include MariaDBServiceProvider in `config/app.php` by adding this
  line to providers:

```php
'providers' => [
    // other exist providers
    YbrNX\MariaDB\MariaDBServiceProvider::class,
]
```

- Set default connection in database configuration to mariadb:

```php
'defaultconnection' => [
    'driver' => 'mariadb',
```

Adding package is done and then you can use functionalities.

In Migrations:

```php
$table->json('field') //CHECK (JSON_VALID(field))
$table->json('field')->nullable() //CHECK (field IS NULL OR JSON_VALID(field))
```

For Query builder:

```php
$query->where('somejson->something->somethingelse', 2)
DB::table('sometable')->select('sometable.somedata', 'sometable.somejson->somedata as somejsondata')
```

Also, JSON_SET() works in MariaDB as in MySQL 5.7:

```php
DB::table('sometable')->where('somejson->somedata', $id)->update(['somejson->otherdata' => 'newvalue']);
```

> Note 1: MariaDB has an alias for JSON datatype since version 10.2.7
>
> Note 2: There is bug in MariaDB < 10.2.8 JSON_EXTRACT() behaviour
> function. It's fixed in MariaDB 10.2.8

[retrieved from](https://github.com/ybr-nx/laravel-mariadb)