# Test JSON data from database and get the column

Tags: php, laravel

I have in my database a column which store a json and I would like to recover the value of a certain object of my json in order to test it

So my column "JSON" contains that

```
{
"type":"index",
"data ":{"index":2}
}
```

And if i receive 2, i need to get this column which contain the index 2 to delete it 
I have tried this:

```
$column = Table::where('JSON["data"]["index"]','=', '2' )
                ->first();
 Table::dropColumn($column);
```

But it doesn't work, beacause i can't get the index

Comment: does casting the column to an array help?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting (look a little further down for JSON -> array casting)

Comment: You could try something like this: `Table::where('json_columnname','like', '%"data ":{"index":2}%' )
                ->first();` Or install a package which adds support for json queries like answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425667/mariadb-json-support-in-laravel

Comment: @RobBiermann tried this but the result is null!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using latest laravel version then,

```
$column = Table::where('JSON->data->index','2')->first();
```

Should work.

You can refer official laravel documentation for json where clause [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses).

Comment: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "data" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Simply use SQL Like

```
->where('JSON', 'like', '%"index": "2"%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Since you gave JSON value as a string, it was unable to get the index value.                                                                                  
   Can you please try like below,                                        
       $column = Table::whereRaw(JSON["data"]["index"], '=', '2' )
                 ->first();                       
                 Table::dropColumn($column);
```

Comment: I tried this but it tell me syntax error it doesn't like putting the JSON like that