# Appending json object in database

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb

Im trying to append new object into json array field

`UPDATE phone_messages SET messages = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(messages, '$', CAST('?' AS JSON)) WHERE charId = ? AND number = ?` this is SQL I'm using but its giving me error (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON)).

Comment: hi, is the cast needed? perhaps append a string without casting

Comment: without casting object is stored as json string, its not similar to other objects in array (in this case I also need to JSON.stringlfy(data) before doing SQL. without that I'm getting [object][object] as string in column)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185598/1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds

Comment: You have another issue with your code that is not causing an error yet: don't put a parameter placeholder `?` inside quotes.